# java spring restful-url with semi-colon

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am currently working on a project that requires the use of a semi-colon in our restful-url scheme.

As you can imagine, we're having issues pulling this off - the underlying Java HTTPServletRequest isn't playing nicely.

Is there a way to work around this issue?

example restulf-URL:

http://service/BOB;MIKE/

Looks like Spring is only working on /service/bob - the ;MIKE gets truncated.

We've tried %3B (or %3F something like that) and it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

ct

Comment: What do you expect to have happen here? Is "MIKE" suppose to be an argument to the "BOB" endpoint or are you expecting that this URL reaches an endpoint named "BOB;MIKE"? Or are you trying to pass "BOB" and "MIKE" as arguments to service/?

Comment: we are trying to get the entire string BOB;MIKE right now, but a list ['bob','mike'] would be ok too. 

right now, java-spring just gets 'bob'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the list of all the delimiters you can legally use in a URI:

```
! $ & ( ) * , ; = + ' : @ / ?
```

try each and see which works for you.

apparently Spring robs you of the `;`. I'm not sure if that's a Servlet thing, but in any case, it sucks. A web framework should allow developers to construct ANY legal URIs.

Comment: turns out it's a servlet thing. there seems to be an error in the Java Servlet API.

Comment: Do you have a reference on that?  I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

While @Amos M. Carpenter answer is correct, here is the required configuration to turn this behavior off :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter 
{
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer)
    {  
        configurer.getUrlPathHelper().setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems this is intentional on Spring's part, but at least it's configurable.

You need to tell your handler mapping to `setRemoveSemicolonContent(false)` (default is `true`). See [the Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMapping.html#setRemoveSemicolonContent-boolean-) for more details.

The reason why this was done is because they apparently wanted to [remove the `;jsessionid=...` suffix](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7818?focusedCommentId=61552&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-61552) from URIs.